# Generating geometric random numbers

Tags: php, random

Is there a geometric random number generator available in PHP 5 like  `numpy.random.geometric` in python ? I tried to find statistics libraries for PHP and [stats_rand_gen_exponential](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.stats-rand-gen-exponential.htm) is the closest function I could find. Or is there a faster and better way to generate geometric random numbers in PHP from what we already have available?

Comment: Yes, there is. Try using http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.stats-rand-gen-exponential.htm

Comment: That is exponential right, I need geometric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a mathematical way to generate geometric random number from a uniform random number [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485448/prove-the-way-to-generate-geometrically-distributed-random-numbers).

Using this method, the following code will generate a geometric random variable with *p=0.1*.

```
$p=0.1;
$geo_rand=floor(log(rand01())/log(1-$p);

function rand01()
{   // auxiliary function
     // returns random number with flat distribution from 0 to 1
        return (float)rand()/(float)getrandmax();
}
```